# How to use sum() within a group_concat()?

Tags: mysql, sum, group-concat

Question revised

### Really wanted a group_concat of sums...

Table: shops

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| shop_id | name   | state  |
+---------+--------+--------+
|    0    | shop 0 |    5   |
|    1    | shop 1 |    5   |
|    2    | shop 2 |    5   |
|    3    | shop 3 |    2   |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

Table: items

```
+------------+--------------+
|   shop  | item | quantity | 
+------------+--------------+
|    0    |  0   |    1     |
|    0    |  1   |    2     |
|    0    |  2   |    3     |
|    1    |  0   |    1     |
|    1    |  1   |    2     |
|    1    |  2   |    3     |
|    2    |  0   |    1     |
|    2    |  1   |    2     |
|    2    |  2   |    3     |
|    3    |  0   |    1     |
|    3    |  1   |    2     |
|    3    |  2   |    3     |
+------------+--------------+

    SELECT state,SUM(i.quantity) total
    FROM shops s2
    LEFT JOIN items i ON i.shop=s2.shopid
    WHERE state=5
    GROUP by item

result #1:

+--------+---------+
| state  |  total  |
+--------+---------+
|    5   |    3    |
+--------+---------+
|    5   |    6    |
+--------+---------+
|    5   |    9    |
+--------+---------+

But I would like the totals, like this:
result #2:
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
| state  | total 0 | total 1 |  total 2 |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|    5   |    3    |     6   |    9     |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+

or using group_concat()
result #3

+--------+---------+
| state  | totals  |
+--------+---------+
|    5   |  3,6,9  |
+--------+---------+
```

I cannot seem to get group_concat to grab the total column in result #1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a way to do this :

```
SELECT state,GROUP_CONCAT(cast(total as char))
FROM
(
    SELECT state,SUM(i.quantity) total
    FROM shops s
    LEFT JOIN items i ON i.shop=s.shopid
    WHERE state=5
    GROUP by item
) s
```

Answer (score 7):

Change:

```
group_concat(CAST(quantity AS CHAR))
```

To

```
SUM(quantity)
```

--

```
SELECT s.`state`, i.`item`, SUM(i.`quantity`) AS quantities
FROM `shops` AS s
    LEFT JOIN `items` AS i ON i.`shop` = s.`shopid`
WHERE s.`state` = 5
GROUP BY i.`item`
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, it was correct for what I originally asked, but what I asked was not what I wanted...

Comment: @mahks - I think you can't get what you want with only one QUERY

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do that in MySQL. Dynamic columns are only supported to the extent of group_contcat() which still aggregates multiple results rows into a single column.

Only if you have a fixed/limited number of `Total X`-s, you can declare them in the query explicitely per se.